# Downlaod .svg image from url

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to download an Image from an Url which looks like this for example: `https://countries.eu/flags/us.svg` And then I want to save it to the Internal Storage. My code I have already is this:

```
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(con.getInputStream());
 saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
```

And the `saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap)`method:

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath = new File(directory, "h.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

It is not working. I don't know why but I just get the Exception `Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'`

Comment: If you want to simply save it as it is, just write the stream without decoding to Bitmap. If you want to render the SVG, use [Sharp](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp). DO NOT save a Bitmap with PNG compression with a .jpg extension, most apps can handle the discrepancy but it's best to just use .png extension.

Comment: To add to that: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() cannot decode an svg file/stream.